# Is it a present progressive(continuous) tense?

Tags: grammar

"He must be starving"

Is it a present progressive (continuous) tense?If your answer is yes then tell me where is "am/is/are".We all know present continuous tense has auxiliary verbs:am,is,are.

Comment: I'd be happy enough to accept *There are people starving in the third world* as a "present progressive" usage, but *I'm starving* seems more like an "adjectival" usage to me (cf *I'm hungry*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The thing about participles though is that they're adjectives and verbs at the same time. Yes, *I'm starving* can be paraphrased as *I'm hungry*, but it can also be paraphrased as *I'm dying of hunger*. I don't think that stative "progressivity" can be so neatly excluded, or that a clear line can be drawn between verbal and deverbal.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, I think there *is* a difference between ***starving*** as a continuous verb and as an adjective. My first example above would still be quite natural if we changed ***starving*** to ***dying*** (another "continuous" form), but it would be at least *slightly* unusual to say *There are people **hungry** in the third world*. I think that's because the "verb" usage naturally *follows* the subject, whereas in the adjectival usage it comes *before* the relevant noun: *There are **hungry** people in the third world*. (Or we have to force in a "real" verb: *people **going** hungry*.)

Answer (score 2):

*He must **be** starving*.

Modal verbs like *must* require that verb heading their complements be cast in the the infinitive form, unmarked with *to*, so 'am, is, are' is expressed by its infinitive form, *be*.